# How to save Mac's plus button window sizes?

Tags: macos, window

The window size sometimes gets saved to a crazy value, like 3x the width of my screen. If I hit the <kbd>+</kbd> button it sizes it appropriately, then if I hit it again it goes to the crazy size again. Sometimes I can get it to remember the two sizes I can switch between.

Is there a way I can reliably set what I want the two window sizes defined by the Mac <kbd>+</kbd> button at the top left of a window for each application?

Answer (score 0):

For setting precise sizes, please check the Mac OS X Automation, you'll have to do some scripting. Some details: [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/training/applescript/11.html)

With less specific window sizes and gestures: [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) or, if u dont mind spending $$$, [Cinch & Sizeup](http://loneplacebo.com/cinch-sizeup-review/)

Comment: Will the script save it, or will I have to rerun the script on the next launch?